# R reshaping data - aggregating data on one part of a table to append to another

Tags: r, reshape, data-manipulation

I have some survey data that I'd like to reshape to be able to interactively slice and dice using filters. However, I'm stuck in how to reshape the data in traditional ways, and I couldn't figure out the appropriate use of the reshape package. Please help!

The data is as follows: each respondent is in a row, along with the responses to each question. In additional columns are multiple demographic columns on the respondent.

```
ID  Q1  Q2  Q3  …   Q30 Demo1   Demo2   Demo3 Average Score
1   1   2   2   …   2   1       1       1     2.5
2   2   3   1   …   5   1       2       1     2.7
3   4   1   5   …   4   2       3       2     1.6
4   1   5   4   …   3   2       1       2     2.5
5   3   4   4   …   1   1       2       2     1.4
```

The goal is to reshape the data to have each unique question/demographic combination be unique, and the average/sample of the scores for that combination as values.

```
Question    Demo1   Demo2   Demo3   Average NumResp
1           1       1       1       3.4     2
1           1       1       2       2.3     5
1           1       1       3       3.1     1
…           …       …       …       …       ...
30          4       5       3       1.3     9
```

As a part 2 to the question, there are also calculations that change the responses from the 1-5 scale into "positive", "neutral" or "negative". It would be great to add this as a column that shows % of all respondents in that specific demographic that was either one of the three, with all 3 values adding up to 100%.

```
Q   Sentiment   Demo1   Demo2   Demo3   Average
1   Positive    1       1       1       3.4
1   Neutral     1       1       1       2.3
1   Negative    1       1       1       3.1
…       …   …   …   …
30  Negative    4       5       3       1.3
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Would prefer to do this in R, though Python will work too.

Comment: `data.table` package (a data.frame extensions) provides the most efficient `melt` and `dcast`. You can read about them in [Efficient reshaping using data.tables](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reshape.html) vignette.

Comment: @jangorecki Thanks for the comment. I just skimmed through the page and it doesn't look too different from the melt and cast/recast function in the reshape package. In this situation, it's not just a simple melt or cast step, it really needs to be melted-and-grouped, splitting the columns into both columns and rows, aggregating data from the columns that become rows (Questions). Do you have any advice on how to use melt and dcast in this example?

Comment: Your expected output doesn't match the input. Please edit for accuracy of proposed solutions.

Comment: It was created to be compatible to reshape2 but it is much faster - see 19th slide from [this pdf](http://user2015.math.aau.dk/presentations/93.pdf). I believe it is also more flexible. Sorry, no advice/answer due to lack of time, just linked you the comprehensive melt/dcast tutorial.

Comment: @PierreLafortune I've edited the example slightly to replace nouns with numbers that match in the output. The use of the numbers may not be the best example, as they mean different things in different situations. In the input, the only times numbers are meant to be numbers are as answer values under the questions. In the output, all values with the exception of average and numresps are dimensions

Comment: Explain the `NumResp` variable.

Comment: @PierreLafortune That's what I referred to as the "sample" - or, the number of respondents that fall into that specific bucket. Adds some dimension to the average column to be able to do weighted averages.

Comment: @PierreLafortune I don't appreciate the consending attitude... you are free to move on. I don't think this question is just using "simple code" and I didn't just throw this up here without first doing research on the available answers on SO/Google and the Reshape package. Your comments add no value to reaching an answer or pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: You misunderstood me. You need to melt the data frame first `m <- melt(df, id.vars=c("Demo1", "Demo2", "Demo3"))` then `aggregate(value~., m, mean)`

Comment: @PierreLafortune Thank you for that clarification. Just a melt doesn't do the job in this case though. What makes this trickier is that the 30 columns of individual Question answers have to also be reduced into one column alongside a 'melt' of the demographic columns. The aggregate values have to be applied across both simultaneously. My apologies for confusion in the original question.

Comment: All of the question columns will melted. When we write the Demo columns out, we are telling the function what not to aggregate but instead use as ids for grouping. And you should take out the ID and Average Score columns as they are not present in your final output

Comment: @PierreLafortune Ah! The behavior of melt just finally clicked for me. The details will be quick to figure out. Upvoted your comments - Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `melt` we can specify the id variables (grouping) or the measure variables ( to collapse to "long"). The argument `variable.name` allows us to name the new variable created by collapsing the wide columns. And `value.name` allows us to name the value column. This is all available and more with the documentation for `?melt.data.frame`.

To create the Sentiment variable we use `cut` to break the value range of scores into thirds. There is an argument called `labels` that allows us to choose the names of the new values.

```
library(reshape2)
m <- melt(df, variable.name="Question", value.name="Average", id=c("Demo1", "Demo2", "Demo3"))
m$Question <- gsub("Q", "", m$Question)
a <- aggregate(Average~., m, mean)
a$Sentiment <- cut(a$Average, seq(1,5,length.out=4), labels=c("Negative", "Neutral", "Postive"), include.lowest=T)
#    Demo1 Demo2 Demo3 Question Average Sentiment
# 1      1     1     1        1       1  Negative
# 2      1     2     1        1       2  Negative
# 3      2     1     2        1       1  Negative
# 4      1     2     2        1       3   Neutral
# 5      2     3     2        1       4   Postive
# 6      1     1     1        2       2  Negative
# 7      1     2     1        2       3   Neutral
# 8      2     1     2        2       5   Postive
# 9      1     2     2        2       4   Postive
# 10     2     3     2        2       1  Negative
```

Note below that I deleted the "ID" and "Average.Score" columns as they will be recalculated in the process.

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(text="
ID  Q1  Q2  Q3     Q30 Demo1   Demo2   Demo3 Average.Score
1   1   2   2      2   1       1       1     2.5
2   2   3   1      5   1       2       1     2.7
3   4   1   5      4   2       3       2     1.6
4   1   5   4      3   2       1       2     2.5
5   3   4   4      1   1       2       2     1.4", header=T)

df <- df[,!names(df) %in% c("ID", "Average.Score")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption, that you have data set like this (make it data.table):

   `ID Q1 Q2 ... Demo1 Demo2 Demo3
1:  1  7  8     2     7     3
2:  2  3  7     6    10     1
3:  3  6  1     5     5     8
4:  4  5  9    10     1     7
5:  5 10  4     8     4     6`

and dictionary of answers scores:

    `value Question Score
 1:     7        1    17
 2:     3        1     6
 3:     6        1    19`

Lets transform data to have Question, Answer, ID, Demo:

`d2 <- melt(dt, id.vars=c('ID', 'Demo1', 'Demo2', 'Demo3'), measure.vars=grep('^Q[0-9]+$', colnames(dt), val=T))
d2[, c('Question', 'variable'):=list(substring(variable,2), NULL)]
R> d2
    ID Demo1 Demo2 Demo3 value Question
 1:  1     2     7     3     7        1
 2:  2     6    10     1     3        1
 3:  3     5     5     8     6        1`

Now let's add scores:
`d3 <- merge(d2, vals_enc, by=c('Question', 'value'))`

And finally get average score and respondents for Question and Demographics:

`d3[, list(Avg=mean(Score), Number=.N), .(Question,Demo1,Demo2,Demo3)]
   Question Demo1 Demo2 Demo3 Avg Number
 1:        1     6    10     1   6      1
 2:        1    10     1     7  18      1
 3:        1     5     5     8  19      1`

Note:
for each Id there is the same demographic status, so number of respondents for each combination of Demographic and Question should be the same.

As it comes to part 2 of the Question:
do you have such calculations or are you looking for them?